# Add an attribute TO A PRODUCT programmatically

Tags: product-attribute, programmatically, magento-1.4

After searching for examples using "magento add attribute to product programmatically" I keep getting copious results on adding or removing ATTRIBUTES programmatically.

I want to programmatically add attribute values *to a specific product* - both the product and the attribute (and options) will have already been created previously.  Something like:

```
function addAttributeToProduct($product, $attribute, $option_value, $scope='global'){ ...
```

Where `$product` could be the object or could be the product SKU, `$attribute` could be the attribute object or the attribute name, etc. with `$option_value`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It should work something along these lines:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
// get the product ID from the sku
$productId = $prod->getIdBySku($product); // if $product is the SKU
// load the product
$productToEdit = $prod->load($productId);
// set the attributes
$productToEdit->setAttributeName(array($options)); // 'AttributeName' is the name of your attribute using CamelCase (eg testattribute = TestAttribute)
// save
$productToEdit->save();
```

To see how the attribute options should be formatted, use var_dump($productToEdit->getAttributeName())